What does a doctor inject Logan Roy with?
In the TV show, Succession, season 1, ep 4, Logan Roy, during his recovery from a serious illness, struggling to attend an official meeting organised by his children.
There is a doctor who injects Logan with an unknown medication; shortly before this injection, this doctor warns Logan about "This may cause long term nerve damage…" and "You are supposed to have three injections in a year, now this is the 3rd injection in a month…".
What injection could this be?

Not my DV but I'm not sure if the medication is that much relevant for the plot though. I haven't watched the show, but my search would go by: 1. Which illness/symptoms? 2. What is usually prescribed after such illness/for treating such symptoms?

Or it could be entirely made up.  The purpose is to show Logan putting his control of the business in front of his health.  He values that more than potnetial nerve damage.  The show is quite vague about his exact health situation - yes he had a stroke in S1E1, but he is also suffering from more chronic conditions than that.
